# Jetty build success, but in the browser i am getting "Error 503 Service Unavailable"

Tags: java, maven

To run my application locally i am building it using 'mvn jetty:run' command. It builds my app properly without any issue.

But still in my browser i am getting an error saying :

```
HTTP ERROR: 503

Problem accessing /s/projectdash/. Reason:

    Service Unavailable
Powered by Jetty://
```

I am not able to understand this issue. any one help me to sort this please?

Comment: stacktrace or it didn't happen